# Gridview's dropdownlist triggers an selectedindexchanged event for all rows beginning with selected row but I only want it to trigger selected row

Tags: vb.net, gridview, selectedindexchanged

For the selected gridview row I need to check server side for value and if it meets criteria display message.  If it doesn't meet criteria it won't display message.  I call javascript to display message.  I have had the code work incorrectly 2 different ways where 1) it cycles through first through last row, and 2) it begins with row selected but continues on the rows AFTER the selected row.  I currently have no looping in place and am baffled why the event loops thru anyway.

ASPX:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="work_id" SortExpression="work_id" 
                                                                                HeaderStyle-Font-Size="Smaller">
                                                                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                                                                    <asp:DropDownList Width="125px" ID="work_dropdown" Font-Size="xx-Small" 
                                                                                        runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("work") %>' OnSelectedIndexChanged="work2_dropdown_SelectedIndexChanged"   CausesValidation="true" AutoPostBack="True" 
                                                                                        DataSourceID="datasource_work" AppendDataBoundItems="true" 
                                                                                        DataTextField="work_value" DataValueField="work_id" Enabled="true"></asp:DropDownList>

                                                                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                                                    <asp:DropDownList Width="125px" ID="work_dropdown" Font-Size="xx-Small" 
                                                                                        runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("work") %>' OnSelectedIndexChanged="work2_dropdown_SelectedIndexChanged" CausesValidation="true" AutoPostBack="True"
                                                                                        DataSourceID="datasource_work" AppendDataBoundItems="true" 
                                                                                        DataTextField="work_value" DataValueField="work_id" enabled="true"></asp:DropDownList>
                                                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                                                            </asp:TemplateField>
```

VB.NET:

```
 Protected Sub work2_dropdown_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)


        Dim row As GridViewRow = Gridview_Assign.SelectedRow


        'Use to look up current cell row
        Dim ddl As DropDownList = CType(sender, DropDownList)
        Dim gvr As GridViewRow = CType(ddl.NamingContainer, GridViewRow)
        Dim rowindex As Integer = gvr.RowIndex
        Dim ddlID As Integer = 0
        ddlID = Convert.ToInt32(ddl.SelectedValue)
        Dim selectedIndex As Integer = Gridview_Assign.SelectedIndex




        Dim test2 As Integer = Gridview_Assign.SelectedIndex
                Dim ddl2 As DropDownList = CType(sender, DropDownList)


        Dim work_dropdown_value As Integer = 0

                Dim work_dropdown_control As DropDownList = CType(gvr.FindControl("work_dropdown"), DropDownList)

                work_dropdown_value = work_dropdown_control.SelectedValue
                work_dropdown_control.Dispose()


                'date2 Due
                Dim date2_due_value As String = ""
                Dim date2_due_value_check As String
                Dim date2_due_control As TextBox = CType(gvr.FindControl("date2_due"), TextBox)

                date2_due_value = date2_due_control.Text

                If date2_due_control.Text = "" Then
                    date2_due_value_check = "1/1/1900"
                Else
                    date2_due_value_check = date2_due_control.Text
                End If

                date2_due_control.Dispose()

                If String.IsNullOrEmpty(date2_due_value) Then
                    date2_due_value = ""
                End If

                'date1 Due
                Dim date1_due_value As String = ""
                Dim date1_due_value_check As String
                Dim date1_due_control As TextBox = CType(gvr.FindControl("date1_due"), TextBox)
                date1_due_value = date1_due_control.Text

                If date1_due_control.Text = "" Then
                    date1_due_value_check = "1/1/1900"
                Else
                    date1_due_value_check = date1_due_control.Text
                End If

                date1_due_control.Dispose()
                Dim work_dropdown_selection As Integer = work_dropdown_control.SelectedValue

                If String.IsNullOrEmpty(date1_due_value) Then
                    date1_due_value = ""
                End If

                If work_dropdown_control.SelectedValue <> 0 Or (work_dropdown_control.SelectedValue <> work_dropdown_value) Then
                    If (date2_due_value <> "" And work_dropdown_value <> 0) Or (date1_due_value <> "" And work_dropdown_value <> 0) Then
                        Dim assignee_available As Boolean = True
                        assignee_available = check_availability(work_dropdown_control.SelectedValue, date1_due_value_check, date2_due_value_check)
                        '  assignee_available = True
                        If assignee_available = False Then

                    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "Javascript", "Javascript:val()", True)


                End If
                    End If
                End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: Can you put your code, please?

Comment: yes.  It is now posted - thank you!  Currently I only have SelectedIndexChanged on the work_dropdown but I have tried adding a Select button, RowDataBound, RowCommand, RowCreated, SelectIndexChanging, javascript, nothing seemed to get me any closer.  This code works great except after it performs current row it goes to all other rows after.  There is no looping here so I don't understand why it doesn't just stop after the current row.

Comment: Probably you change the Selected Index of the dropdown control to the next element in the list which trigger work2_dropdown_SelectedIndexChanged event again.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid triggering the event again?

Comment: Please Boris can you elaborate?